# Weird Java problem, while loop termination

Tags: java, termination

I have a piece of code that looks like this:

```
Algorithm a = null;  
while(a == null)  
{  
    a = grid.getAlgorithm();  
}
```

getAlgorithm() in my Grid class returns some subtype of Algorithm depending on what the user chooses from some options.

My problem is that even after an algorithm is selected, the loop never terminates. However, that's not the tricky bit, if I simply place a System.out.println("Got here"); after my call to getAlgorithm(), the program runs perfectly fine and the loop terminates as intended.

My question is: why does adding that magic print statement suddenly make the loop terminate?

Moreover, this issue first came up when I started using my new laptop, I doubt that's related, but I figured it would be worth mentioning.

Edit: The program in question is NOT multithreaded. The code for getAlgorithm() is:

```
public Algorithm getAlgorithm ()  
{  
    return algorithm;  
}
```

Where algorithm is initially null, but will change value upon some user input.

Comment: Oh dear please tell me you aren't looping like this while waiting for user input...

Comment: The only way for that to happen that I can see is if a returns null. If it's not null, the loop will exit. Check the source of `getAlgorithm()` or print out its contents in the loop to confirm it's not null.

Comment: @Travis - Looks more like an iterator to me, doing a linear search for the first non-null Algorithm. But who knows?

Comment: I'd agree with Travis, an iterator should be named getNextAlgorythm(). But yeah, only user657183 knows ...

Comment: Is this the actual code? What's in `getAlgorithm` and are you sure it is returning something non-`null`? If you put the `println` call in `getAlgorithm` just before it returns a non-`null` value, does it still exit cleanly?

Comment: I added a prntln to getAlgorithm as you recommended, and it doesn't work.

Comment: If this is not multi-threaded, where is the user input coming from?

Comment: +1 to @Matthew. There's no way that `algorithm` can change unless there is a separate execution thread. If there is, then the `getAlgorithm()` method may not see the change unless it is executed in a synchronized block or `algorithm` is declared volatile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing active polling. This is a bad practice. You should at least let the polling thread sleep (with Thread.sleep). Since println does some io, it probably does just that. If your app is not multithreaded it is unlikely to work at all.

Comment: How do you know this is active polling? Who knows what goes on inside getAlgorithm()? OP hasn't told us. Perhaps each call mutates `grid`, so each call might return a different value than the preceding one.

Comment: Description of op indicates waiting for user input. The problem seems to be a synchronisation problem. Travis seems to agree. Mutating a grid, ie a UI object in a loop like this would be a bad and confusing practice. Sounds like a fair bet to me.

Comment: The funny part is that the code ran fine on my old computer, but running it on my new one produces this peculiar bug. So I know the code, in theory, SHOULD work.

Comment: @J.N. How is that active polling? It's obtaining user input (not polling for it) and looping until it is acceptable.

Comment: @Ted In a windowed environment, one where you have a grid component, you don't do a while loop on user input while its valid. You'd rather use events to get notified of change.

Comment: @DEomachus: please add more info on the context, how does that code get called, and what does the getAlgorithm function does in your question description. I can see good reasons why some weak multithread code would fail on one machine and work on another one.

Comment: @Deomachus: If code works sometimes, this does not mean it SHOULD work everywhere. In your case you have a threading problem, even if you don't see it yet.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the issue has to deal with how grid.getAlgorithm is executed. If there is very little cost associated with executing the method, then your while loop will cycle very quickly as long the method continues to return null. That is often referred to as a [busy wait](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy-wait).

Now it sounds like your new laptop is encountering a [starvation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_starvation) issue which didn't manifest on your old computer. It is hard to say why but if you look at the link I included above, the Wikipedia article does indicate that busy waits do have unpredictable behavior. Maybe your old computer handles user IO better than your new laptop. Regardless, on your new laptop, that loop is taking resources away from whatever is handling your user IO hence it is starving the process that is responsible for breaking the loop.

Answer (score 1):

If this loop is to wait for user input in a GUI then ouch. Bad, bad idea and even with `Thread.sleep()` added I'd never recommend it. Instead, you most likely want to register an event listener on the component in question, and only have the validation code fire off when the contents change.

It's more than likely you're program is locking up because you've reached some form of deadlock more than anything else, especially if your application is multithreaded. Rather than try to solve this issue and hack your way round it, I'd seriously consider redesigning how this part of the application works.

Comment: If his loop was written: `while (!line.equals("stop")) { line = getNextLine(); }`, would you call that a "Bad, bad idea"? I don't see any difference here.

Comment: I've edited my post to make it clearer, but I meant if he was polling on some form of GUI that's a terrible idea. The difference with `getNextLine()` is you're actually getting something new each time.

Comment: OP wrote: "getAlgorithm() in my Grid class returns some subtype of Algorithm depending on what the user chooses from some options." Sounded like a glorified `getNextLine()` to me. **But** based on OP's edit (done after my comment), I agree that there's a threading problem here.

Answer (score 0):

You should check getAlgorithm(), there must be something wrong in the method.

Answer (score 0):

There are two scenarios:

1. Your code is really not meant to be multi-threaded. In this case you need to insert some sort of user input in the loop. Otherwise you might as well leave it as Algorithm a = grid.getAlgorithm(); and prevent the infinite loop.
2. Your code is multi-threaded in which case you have some sort of 'visibility' problem.  Go to [Atomicity, Visibility and Ordering](http://jeremymanson.blogspot.com/2007/08/atomicity-visibility-and-ordering.html) or read [Java Concurrency in Practice](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321349601) to learn more about visibility.  Essentially it means that without some sort of synchronization between threads, the thread you are looping in may never find out that the value has changed due to optimizations the JVM may perform.

You did not mention any context around how this code is run.  If it is a console based application and you started from a 'main' function, you would know if there was multi-threading. I am assuming this is not the case since you say there is no multithreading.  Another option would be that this is a swing application in which case you should read [Multithreaded Swing Applications](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Threads/swing/). It might be a web application in which case a similar case to swing might apply.

In any case you could always debug the application to see which thread is writing to the 'algorithm' variable, then see which thread is reading from it.

I hope this is helpful. In any case, you may find more help if you give a little more context in your question. Especially for a question with such an intriguing title as 'Weird Java problem, while loop termination'.